# Changing second occurrence of textfield in a SwiftUI List based on repeating pattern in array

Tags: arrays, listview, swiftui, textfield

When given a pattern such as ABAB for 4 text fields, I'm trying to figure out how to populate the second textfield occurrence of each letter with the last word of the sentence typed in the first textfield occurrence of that letter. So if "What the heck" is typed in the first line with the pattern ABAB, the third line will auto-populate with "heck". I already know how to filter the last word out of a sentence, just struggling with the rest.

How I have the list in mention set up currently: [Canvas Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S20gz.png)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var textFields: [String]
    var patternLetters = ["A", "B", "A", "B"]

    init(){
        _textFields = State(initialValue: Array(repeating: "", count: 4))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<4) { line in
            HStack {
                TextField("Enter a sentence", text: self.$textFields[line])
                Spacer()
                Text(self.patternLetters[line])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really hacky solution but it does the job quite well:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var textFields: [String]
    var patternLetters = ["A", "B", "A", "B"]

    init(){
        _textFields = State(initialValue: Array(repeating: "", count: 4))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<4) { line in
            HStack {
                TextField("Enter a sentence", text: Binding(
                    get: {
                        // Check if this is the first occurence of the letter
                        if self.patternLetters.firstIndex(of: self.patternLetters[line]) != line {
                            // is not first occurence so return last work of first occurence 
                            return String(self.textFields[self.patternLetters.firstIndex(of: self.patternLetters[line]) ?? 0].split(separator: " ").last ?? "")
                        } else {
                            return self.textFields[line]
                        }
                        
                        
                    },
                    set: { (newValue) in
                       return self.textFields[line] = newValue
                }))
                Spacer()
                Text(self.patternLetters[line])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Gif of code working]

The code I provided is just to demonstrate how it can be done and is not save in the scenario of e.g. when the array is generated post launch of the app.
If the array is not pre defined and final be sure to check if the indexes are available. Otherwise you risk in running into errors of: Index out of range

Comment: Thank you answered my question perfectly. Would there be a way to still allow a user to add or edit text in the auto-populated textfields in any sort of way, or would that require a different approach than the through the get: method?

Comment: Like if I'd rather have the user type out a sentence, and it autocompletes the last word with the last from the previous one in the pattern. (Feel no obligation to answer as you answered the first perfectly, and I don't need help programming the autocomplete, just storing that last word in a variable that I could eventually place into the autocomplete once I program it)

Comment: In that case modify the ```set``` to append the last work of the corresponding predecessor